# Convert JQuery ajax GET to POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this jquery ajax get method on an Index razor in my application:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("SubmitProjectForPreapproval", "api/Project")",
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    data: { projectId: "@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["ProjectId"]" }
}).done(function (data) {

    var count = 0;
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        $("#ulMessages").append("<li>" + value + "</li>");
        count++;
    });

    // Assume validation errors if more than 1 message
    if (count > 1) {
        $("#btnSubmit").removeAttr("disabled");
    }

}).fail(function () {

    $("#ulMessages").append("<li>An error occurred. Please try again later</li>");
    $("#btnSubmit").removeAttr("disabled");

}).always(function () {

    $("#imgAjaxLoader").hide();

});
```

This calls a method within the api/project controller that returns a list of strings:

```
[HttpGet]
public List<string> SubmitProjectForPreapproval(int projectId)
{ ... }
```

What I want to do is convert this to an ajax post method. I've been struggling to do just that for the better part of the day. My question is, what is everything that needs to change in order for this to happen? e.g. - change attribute of the method to `[HttpPost]`, and how do I send it the route value? (int pojectId)

Edit: If I do this it works for some reason:

```
public List<string> SubmitProjectForPreapproval(/*int projectId*/)
{
    int projectId = 3308;
    ...
}
```

Not sure why it doesn't find my method if I have the parameter there.

Comment: Why dont you change the `type` to `POST` from `GET` in ajax call

Comment: @dreamweiver: Yeah. That's pretty much what I'm trying to do. I posted the working version with the GET above.

Comment: Andrew is correct here, or you can use the $.post method as well, which is shorthand for the $.ajax type : post method.  Basically if type is not specified ajax will use GET so specify type : "POST" as a parameter

Comment: I have discovered the use of Fiddler to discover what's actually going wrong: I'm potentially not passing my route values correctly. Its saying "No action was found on the controller `Project` that matches the request." If I take the parameter out of the method in the controller, it finds the action. e.g.: `public List<string> SubmitProjectForPreapproval()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed the way I was sending the data to the controller action. I fixed it by doing the following:

- Alter the ajax method (make use of JSON.stringify):

```
var projectIdObject = {
    ProjectId: "@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["ProjectId"]",
}

$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("SubmitProjectForPreapproval", "api/Project")",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(projectIdObject),
        contentType: 'application/json',
    }).done(function (data) { ... }
```

- Add a class to take this stringified value:

```
public class ProjectIdObject
{
    public string ProjectId { get; set; }
}
```

- Alter the controller action method to receive this new object and extract the value I want:

```
[HttpPost]
public List<string> SubmitProjectForPreapproval(ProjectIdObject projectIdObject)
{
    int projectId = int.Parse(projectIdObject.ProjectId);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how the **@Url** stuff formats with your system - but just changing it to something like:

`$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("SubmitProjectForPreapproval", "api/Project")",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    data: { projectId: "@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["ProjectId"]" }
}).done(function (data) {`

If you're bit:

`@Url.Action("SubmitProjectForPreapproval`

..actually has any ?xxx values in it, you also need to add them into the `data: { ...  }`